# Radeon DVI errors filling logs

Tags: debian-wheezy, dmesg

These error just fill my logs:

```
[316094.848311] [drm:radeon_dvi_detect] *ERROR* DVI-I-1: probed a monitor but no|invalid EDID
[316104.895726] [drm:drm_edid_block_valid] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 128
[316104.898492] Raw EDID:
[316104.901300]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.904245]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.907191]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.910137]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.912948]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.915620]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.918152]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.920589]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.951274] [drm:drm_edid_block_valid] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 128
[316104.953906] Raw EDID:
[316104.956597]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.959421]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.962250]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.965081]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.967907]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.970590]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.973136]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316104.975625]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.006315] [drm:drm_edid_block_valid] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 128
[316105.008953] Raw EDID:
[316105.011641]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.014475]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.017310]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.020144]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.022982]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.025683]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.028234]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.030689]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.061394] [drm:drm_edid_block_valid] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 128
[316105.064038] Raw EDID:
[316105.066736]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.069589]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.072429]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.075263]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.078103]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.080804]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.083339]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.085794]         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[316105.088272] radeon 0000:0c:01.0: DVI-I-1: EDID block 0 invalid.
[316105.088275] [drm:radeon_dvi_detect] *ERROR* DVI-I-1: probed a monitor but no|invalid EDID
```

Is there aything I can do to suppress them or tell the driver to probing the monitor or disable DVI port?

I'm running Debian 7 with only a cli as a LAMP server. THere is no GDM nor GUI nor anything like that.

Comment: Think I found a solution here: http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/9793-radeon-EDID-error

Comment: Can you remove the AMD video adapter from the machine? They _really_ dislike not having a monitor attached.

Comment: NO not really. It's a server in colo. I think it's built into the SUPERMICRO motherboard.

Comment: That's odd, usually they use a cheap Matrox or something rather than a more expensive AMD or NVIDIA GPU. Double check what's actually in the machine.

Comment: Yup it's there: 0c:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI ES1000 (rev 02)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix it by:
editing /etc/default/grub

```
# add nomodeset
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

## update grub

update-grub

reboot