# Terminal outputs *ERROR* VGa-1: probed a monitor but no:invalid EDID over and over again

Tags: centos, centos7

**Situation:**

Using one of these "HDMI VGA DVI LCD Control Board For LP154WX4 LP154W01 N154I2 1280x800 LCD Screen" and hooking up my CentOS 7 Desktop via VGA cable to my old laptop monitor using this control board. I can see the terminal and type commands and everything.

The problem is the terminal outputs this message over and over again every 5 seconds or so, even when using nano or when in the middle of typing a terminal command. (beginning number changes with each output):

```
[ 35.418845] [drm:radeon_vga_detect [radeon]] *ERROR* VGa-1: probed a monitor but no:invalid EDID
```

**What I've got so far:**

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=58298 says:

> I found a reasonable answer.
>
> 1) Typically EDID error message may be
>   simple because of VGA cable problems. I found that other monitor works
>   w/the same cable normally, therefore it's a monitor problem.
>
> 2) It's
>   only EDID data problem - I works normally w/this monitor under Windows
>   7.
>
> 3) It's possible to suppress EDID work w/X11 . It's necessary simple to put to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d the configuration file with
>
> Option "Ignore EDID" "1" 
>   Modes "1366x768" ... "800x600"

Which I don't think is applicable to CentOS 7.

And this [Radeon DVI errors filling logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/708400/radeon-dvi-errors-filling-logs) which is a solution for debian-wheezy.

**Question:**

What do you recommend to do? Any ideas on how to make it into a valid VGA connection or suppressing the terminal outputs?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you copy and paste that log message? It appears to have typos in it.

Comment: No, I had to look at the other monitor and type it on my laptop. The message is pretty similar to https://serverfault.com/questions/708400/radeon-dvi-errors-filling-logs but mine's VGA